# Check designated initializer in xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, designated-initializer

Is there any way to find out which initializer is the designated one in super class in Xcode? 
I type super().init.. then, Xcode shows all initializers of superclass. I want to know is there any sign or symbol to point out which is the designated one?

Also a quick question. A designated initializer(DI) in subclass is allowed to only call a convenience initializer(CI) in superclass since the CI in superclass will eventually call the DI in superclass. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: I am lacking this option often. Don't understand why it's not provided, when typing super.init you essentially get a bunch of invalid completions, which makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, any initializer not marked with the keyword "convenience" is a designated initializer.

And designated initializers are required to call a designated initializer in their immediate superclass, per [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203). They cannot call a convenience initializer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone new to Xcode - this confused me for a while too. The absence of the `convenience` keyword is what defines a designated initializer, but depending on where you look, *you won't always see the 'convenience' keyword*.

You *can* see the `convenience` keyword:

- on the 'Developer documentation' page for the *individual* initializer
- in the 'Quick help' (right click > Show quick help, or the 'Quick help' pane on the right)
- in the definition of the class in Xcode (right click > Jump to definition)

You *can't* see it when looking at the overview of the class in the 'Developer documentation', or in code suggestions as you type.

(Using Xcode 13.1)